# Access the template information by folder name [DocuSign]

Tags: docusignapi

I see that you can access the `template` data, by providing the `templateID` or the `folderID`.

But does the api let us access the template info by providing the **folder name**. Let's say I have the following folder structure.

```
- UserDetails
    - EN
        Template_1_EN
        .....
    - FR
        Template_1_FR
        .....
```

I have been referencing the following docs
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templates/

Answer (score 0):

Currently if you want to find all templates based on the name of the folder they are in, you would have to make two API calls:

1. Find the **folderID** for the folder you are looking for.
2. Use the **folderID** to search for templates in that folder as you mentioned.

To do #1 you would need to call the endpoint to list folders - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/list/

Note that there's no query parameter to search by the name either, and you'll just have to get all folders and find the one that you want and find its **folderID**.